# "Better" scala stack traces

Tags: scala, stack-trace

Scala stack traces are complex, mostly because of the way anonymous functions are translated to bytecode. Here's a example:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$$anonfun$go$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcII$sp(IdentityVerifier.scala:19)
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$$anonfun$go$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(IdentityVerifier.scala:17)
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$$anonfun$go$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(IdentityVerifier.scala:17)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$$anonfun$go$2.apply(IdentityVerifier.scala:17)
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$$anonfun$go$2.apply(IdentityVerifier.scala:16)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at com.company.IdentityVerifier$.go(IdentityVerifier.scala:16)
    at com.company.UserMap.setLastUserId(UserMap.scala:12)
    at com.company.UserConsumer.setCurrentUser(UserConsumer.java:69)
    at com.company.UserConsumer.consume(UserConsumer.java:64)
    at com.company.UserProducer.execute(UserProducer.java:19)
    at com.company.UserCreator.execute(UserCreator.java:18)
    at com.company.UserCreatorMain$1.run(UserCreatorMain.java:37)
    at com.company.UserCreatorMain.main(UserCreatorMain.java:51)
```

I've found [stackifier](http://stackifier.takipi.com/scala.html) (it's their example), but it's a pain to keep pasting stack traces to a webpage. Is there a way to print "better" stack traces automatically?

Comment: How is the stack trace complex? It tells you the line where the exception happened.

Comment: @vptheron The point of a stack trace is not only to know the line where the exception happened, but also *how it got there*. "Complex" is mostly subjective - to me, `$$anonfun$go$2$$anonfun$apply$2` doesn't tell me any useful information, neither do 5 lines of trace for a simple `flatMap`. Although it's certainly interesting to have a peek at scala's internals, for most of the time I'd rather just understand *what went wrong*. Fast.

Comment: Technically, the problem with this Scala stack trace is that it's not a Scala stack trace, it's a Java stack trace. Doesn't help you, though.

Comment: Much like debugging C++ template compiler errors, you just "learn" to read these things.

Answer (score 5):

Intellij IDEA helps, even in the case you are not debugging the code (and the scala plugin should work even with the community version) :

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/analyzing-external-stacktraces.html

You get a clickable stack trace that jumps to the right place.

I asked at ScalaIDE forums whether ScalaIDE does this too.  Mirco Dotta ninja-responded:

> Yes it does, but it's not the simplest feature to find in Eclipse. You need to [open the "Java StackTrace Console"](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-stacktrace_console.htm)

Haven't asked about emacs, somebody please chip in.

Also, please try to consider that "cryptic" names (go see c++ name mangling) is a price you pay for added flexibility.